# Powershell: how to replace first ":" in a string to be ","?

Tags: string, powershell, replace

For example, I've got a text file indicating writers of powershell scripts, each line looks like:

```
Hello world.ps1:John Smith
Dowork.ps1:Blake Benn
```

I wish to find first ":" in each line and replace with "," so I can get a csv file,

```
Hello world.ps1,John Smith
Dowork.ps1,Blake Benn
```

I tried with "-replace", but failed:

```
"Hello World.ps1:John Smith" -replace ":" ","

At line:1 char:43
+ "Hello World.ps1:John Smith" -replace ":" ","
+                                           ~~~
Unexpected token '","' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
    ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you truly want to replace *only the first `:`*, use `-replace '^(.*?):(.*)','$1,$2'` rather than `-replace ":",","`

Comment: VTC as typo per accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the `-replace` operator is not correct. Read the help for the operator carefully - `help about_Comparison_Operators`. You are missing a `,` between the find and replace strings.

```
PS C:\> "Hello World.ps1:John Smith" -replace ":",","
Hello World.ps1,John Smith
```

Comment: But keep in mind, as @MathiasRJessen pointed out in a separate comment, that this will replace *all* occurrences, not just the *first* occurrence as the question requires. If there is only one then, yes, this is sufficient.

Comment: Correct - however this doesn't seem to be a problem based on the OP's sample data.