# powershell: how to remove first # in each row of text?

Tags: string, powershell, replace

E.g. I've got a text file like this:

```
abc,#32432,he#llo
xyz,#989,wor#ld
```

I wish to change it to be:

```
abc,32432,he#llo
xyz,989,wor#ld
```

Just remove first "#" from each row. How to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Same answer as your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914083/): Use the `-replace` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only change the first `#` in a string you could use a regular expression like this

```
"abc,#32432,he#llo" -replace '(.*?)#(.*$)', '${1}${2}'
```

Explanation as by Regexbuddy

```
# (.*?)#(.*$)
# 
# Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Parentheses capture
# 
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
#    Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Match the character “#” literally «#»
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*$)»
#    Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
#    Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»
```

Comment: Nice tool, Regexbuddy

Comment: I'm not affiliated in any way so it's safe for me to say that you will not regret buying it *(including Powergrep)*. You might like RegexMagic too but that was not a match for me *(bought it, don't perse regret it but never use it)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple regex that replaces a hash that follows a section of non hashes with nothing, something like this:

```
Get-Content input_file.txt | % {$_ -replace '(?<=^[^#]+)#'} | Set-Content output_file.txt
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how this worked, mainly because of a lack of powershell knowledge regarding lookaheads. Upside is certainly size. Downside is speed of execution *(should that matter much)*